# How to exclude retweets and replies from Twitter API Full-archive search

Tags: postman, tweets, twitterapi-python

I am trying to extract some historical tweets using twitter API. And I want to exclude retweets and replies. I tried other suggested answers here but nothing seem to work. Can someone please help me, I am struggling since a week to find the resources. Below is my endpoint for Full-archive search.

https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all?query=MMIW OR MMIP OR MMIWG&start_time=2015-01-01T00:00:01Z&end_time=2015-01-15T23:59:01Z&max_results=500&tweet.fields=created_at,entities,geo,id,referenced_tweets,in_reply_to_user_id,lang,possibly_sensitive,source,text,withheld&place.fields=country,full_name&user.fields=created_at,description,location,name,pinned_tweet_id,username,verified,withheld

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured out from twitter's rules and filtering operators from the link below:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/rules-and-filtering/operators-by-product

i just had to add and negate the is:retweet operaor in my query field.
Ex: query=(MMIW OR MMIP OR MMIWG) -is:retweet
So, my modified endpoint that worked:

https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all?start_time=2015-01-01T00:00:01Z&end_time=2015-01-15T23:59:59Z&max_results=500&tweet.fields=created_at,entities,geo,id,lang,possibly_sensitive,source,text,withheld,in_reply_to_user_id,referenced_tweets&place.fields=country,country_code,full_name,geo,id,name&query=(MMIW OR MMIP OR MMIWG) -is:retweet&user.fields=created_at,description,location,name,pinned_tweet_id,username,verified

Comment: is:retweet is a paid filter option for v2